# Equivalence Relations using Quotients

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

I need help with this problem:
Let $A$ resp. $B$ be a set, endowed with an equivalence relation $\sim_A$ resp. $\sim_B$. Defne a relation $\sim$ on $A \times B$ by setting

$$(a_1, b_1) \sim (a_2, b_2) \Leftrightarrow a_1\sim_A a_2 \ \text{and} \ b_1 \sim_B b_2.$$

Use the universal property for quotients to establish that there are functions

$$(A \times B)/\sim \ \rightarrow \ A/\sim_A$$
and
$$(A \times B)/\sim \ \rightarrow \ B/\sim_B.$$

Comment: $A\times B\to A/\sim_A$ and $A\times B\to B/\sim_B$ are constant on equivalence clases, hence ...

Comment: they are contained in the class?

Answer (score 0):

The *kernel* of a function $f:X\to Y$ is the equivalence relation $\theta_f$ on $X$ which satisfies
$$x\,\theta_f\, x' \iff f(x)=f(x') \,.$$
Prove that $f$ factors through $X/R$ for some equivalence relation $R$ iff $R$ implies $\theta_f$ (i.e. $\forall x,x':\, xRx' \Rightarrow x\,\theta_f\, x'$).

Now use the composition $p:A\times B\to A\to A/\sim_A$  and check that $\sim$ implies $\theta_p$.